# Markov Chain Expectation

Tags: expectation, markov-chains

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a markov chain on a countable set $S$, and $P_x (\tau_y < \infty) = 1$ for all $x,y \in S$. Let $h : S \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be harmonic. Is it true that $ E_x [h(X_{\tau_y})] = h(y) $ ?

From the definition of expectation,

$$ E_x [h(X_{\tau_y})] = \sum_{s \in S} P_x (X_{\tau_y} = s)h(s) $$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you have $X_{\tau_y} = y$ almost surely?

Comment: $\tau_y$ is the first hitting time of y? Then $X_{\tau_y}$ is y a.s., since the hitting time is almost surely finite...

Comment: Could you give a more detailed derivation? I am confused on how to relate $ \tau_y $ and $ X_{\tau_y} $ mathematically.

Comment: What is your definition of $\tau_y$?

Comment: $ \tau_y = \inf\{n \in \mathbb{N} : X_n = y\} $

Comment: Okay, so it's the smallest n so that $X_n = y$. If we wait until the first time that X_n is y, and then check what value X_n is, what do you expect to get?

Comment: Since it is the first time that $ X_n $ is $ y $, then it must be the smallest $ n $ and, therefore $ X_n = X_{\tau_y} = y $. Am I right? And we have $ P_x(X_{\tau_y} = y) = 1 $ for all $ y \in S $. How do i relate it to the sum to get $ h(y) $?

Comment: You have $ P_x(X_{\tau_y} = y) = 1$, and as such, $$ P_x(X_{\tau_y} = s) = \begin{cases} 1, & s = y \\ 0, & s \neq y \end{cases}. $$ Now what can you say about the sum? (Perhaps what may confuse you is that harmonicity of $h$ is completely irrelevant to the entire argument. The equality is true simply because $X_{\tau_y} = y$ holds $P_x$-almost surely.)

Comment: That's clear now, thanks.